# Which real world computers are the workstations shown at the Daily Planet in the DCAU show Superman: The Animated Series based on?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, superman-the-animated-series

Here are some images of the workstations used by the reporters at the Daily Planet:

[image: Workstations at the Daily Planet in the DCAU show Superman: The Animated Series]

[image: Clark Kent working on his workstation at the Daily Planet, Superman: The Animated Series, DCAU]

[image: Clark Kent printing out something from his workstation at the Daily Planet, Superman: The Animated Series, DCAU]

Which real world computers are these workstations based on?

Comment: It should be a Tandy - [gizmodo - that-stupid-time-superman-shilled-computers-for-radio-shack](https://gizmodo.com/that-stupid-time-superman-shilled-computers-for-radio-s-5835188)

Comment: If anyone is wondering, the last screenshot most likely comes from the episode "Mxyzpixilated"

Comment: @Clockwork, all the screenshots are from that episode.

Comment: I suspect the 1950s philco predicta tv is an influence.  I think we should give credit to the artist for a 1930s art deco 1980s computer terminal.  It may not be deeper than that.

Answer (score 22):

I would assume that the 'look' is based on these sorts of adverts from the 1970s showing [IBM 327x](http://terminals-wiki.org/wiki/index.php/IBM_3277) terminals.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The very wide screens with rounded edges also reminded me of this:  https://gamesnostalgia.com/screenshot/where-in-europe-is-carmen-sandiego/53206 and I'm pretty sure I've seen that specific screen shape (probably with the narrow base/stand) somewhere else as well.  However, I don't recall if it was on a real kind of 1960s-era device, or in another fictional context with a "raygun gothic" esthetic similar to Superman:  The Animated Series.

Comment: Why are there ghosts in the first picture?

Comment: @NickMatteo: I suspect this is a kind of "one man running the whole office" style picture, showing him in everyone's position.

Comment: @NickMatteo It's actually Clark Kent/Superman moving so fast that he appears to be several places at once.

Answer (score 12):

I think they are not based on a real-world computer at all, but on the look of a traditional writing desk with a [banker's lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker%27s_lamp). This is a kind of desk lamp with a long green lampshade. Such lamps are apparently common in public libraries in the US. The overall scene looks similar to scenes set in libraries in US movies.

[image]
<sub><sup>**Se7en**</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: https://thebankerslamp.com/green-desk-lamp-movies/ - Some possible examples here to choose from. I've taken the liberty of editing in a picture from the library scene in the movie Se7en.

Comment: Although the OP's artwork also showed a banker's light on each desk. However I broadly agree with the premise: the artist possibly had only a very sketchy idea of what a computerised office would look like so expanded a familiar theme.